# Ошибка: error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Kniga'

Tags: c++

Компилятор ругается на ошибку

```
Error   5   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Kniga'
```

Исходная задача: Создать 2 класса: класс Книга и класс СписокКниг.

1. Напиши класс Kniga, private: char *avtor, char *nazwa
2. Напиши конструктор. Внимание, здесь мы имеем указатели на массив, потому конструктор должен создать массив и копировать текст.
3. Напиши конструктор по умолчанию, который инициализирует указатели как NULL(0)
4. Напиши конструктор копирования. Создает массив и копирует текст.
5. Напиши метод vypishy, которая выводит на экран элементы класса.
6. Напиши деструктор.
7. Напиши класс SpisokKnig, private: knigi - указатель на массив типа Kniga, skolkoKnig - сколько книг в списку, maxKnig - максимальная длина массива.
8. Конструктор класса SpisokKnig (принимает 1 параметр - длину массива). Конструктор создает динамический массив. Какой конструктор класса Kniga здесь сработает?
9. Напиши метод dobavitKnigu - с параметром класса Kniga, который в первую свободную ячейку массива запишет новую книгу .
10. Напиши метод vypisyVse - выводит на экран все книги.

Вот код, возможно что-то в другом месте написал не правильно и потому не компилируется код.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

class Kniga{
private: char *autor;
         char *nazva;
public: Kniga(char *, char *);
        Kniga();
        Kniga(const Kniga &);
        void vypishy();
        ~Kniga();
};

Kniga::Kniga(char *konstr_autor, char *konstr_nazva){
    autor = new char[strlen(konstr_autor) + 1];
    strcpy(autor, konstr_autor);

    nazva = new char[strlen(konstr_nazva) + 1];
    strcpy(nazva, konstr_nazva);
}

Kniga::~Kniga(){
    delete[] autor;
    delete[] nazva;
}

Kniga::Kniga(){
    autor = NULL;
    nazva = NULL;
}

Kniga::Kniga(const Kniga &kniga){
    autor = new char[strlen(autor) + 1];
    strcpy(autor, kniga.autor);

    nazva = new char[strlen(nazva) + 1];
    strcpy(nazva, kniga.nazva);
}

void Kniga::vypishy(){
    if (autor != NULL && nazva != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Autor: " << autor << endl;
        cout << "Nazva: " << nazva << endl;
    }
}

class SpisokKnig{
    int maxKnig;
    Kniga *knigi;
    static int skolkoKnig;
public:
    SpisokKnig(int);
    void dobavitKnigu(char *aut, char *naz);
    void vypishyVse();
};

int SpisokKnig::skolkoKnig = 0;

SpisokKnig::SpisokKnig(int maxKn){
    maxKnig = maxKn;
    knigi = new Kniga[maxKnig];
}

void SpisokKnig::dobavitKnigu(char *aut, char *naz){
    knigi[skolkoKnig] = Kniga(aut, naz);
    skolkoKnig++;
}

void SpisokKnig::vypishyVse(){
    for (int i = 0; i < skolkoKnig; i++)
        cout << knigi[i] << endl;   //ругается здесь
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Kniga kniga("Jack Back", "My Book");

    SpisokKnig spisok(3);
    spisok.dobavitKnigu("Nick Tirik", "New book");
    spisok.dobavitKnigu("Vova Mill", "Vova's life");
    spisok.vypishyVse();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вместо `cout << knigi[i] << endl;` вызывай vypishy у книги: `knigi[i].vypishy()`

Comment: @Taras Haliuk Откуда компилятор должен знать, как выводить на консоль объекты класса kniga в этом предложении  cout << knigi[i] << endl; ? Он впервые в жизни видит этот код.

Answer (score 2):

Ну допишите этот оператор, типа

```
class Kniga{
private: char *autor;
         char *nazva;
public: Kniga(char *, char *);
        Kniga();
        Kniga(const Kniga &);
        void vypishy();
        ~Kniga();
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Kniga& k);

};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Kniga& k)
{
    return os << "(" << k.author<< " : " << k.nazva << ")";
}
```